# Unable to do "git push" to newly created branch

Tags: git, git-push

I followed instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branching+a+Repository) to create a new branch. I executed the following commands from an EC2 Instance where I've cloned the repo:

```
$ git branch
  * master
$ git branch solr
$ git checkout solr
$ git branch
   master
  * solr
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "adding a change from the feature branch"
$ git checkout master
$ git push origin solr
```

But the push command gives me the following error:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm a newbie to git. Please could someone help.
Thanks

Comment: What does `git remote` show?

Comment: @raina77ow : it shows nothing..

Comment: And how exactly have you cloned the existing repository then?

Comment: @raina77ow : `git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git`

Comment: Are you in the same directory? Could you add `.git/config` contents to the question?

Comment: @raina77ow : Actually it was cloned from a different machine by a colleague. Could that be the problem. `.git/config` gives `-su: .git/config: Permission denied`

Comment: @raina77ow : I'm in the same directory. All the previous commands were successful

Comment: "Actually it was cloned from a different machine by a colleague" - again, how exactly?

Comment: @raina77ow : `git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote was missing. Fixed using:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/usr/repo
```

Comment: `git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/usr/repo`